# Как записать HashMap в TXT

Tags: java

Как записать HashMap в txt файл я когда записую своим способом там у меня страшные вещи в тхт и как сделать проверку существует ли файл?

```
 HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "windows-1251");
        String date = new Date().toString();
        while (true) {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            if (s.equals("end")) {
                break;
            } else {
                hm.put(date, s);
            }
            for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> item : hm.entrySet()) {
                System.out.printf(
                        "Key: %s  Value: %s \n", item.getKey(), item.getValue());
            }
            try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream("test.txt"))) {
                oos.writeObject(hm);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final String FILE_NAME = "1.txt";

        Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("k1", "v1");
        hm.put("k2", "v2");
        hm.put("k3", "v3");

        Files.write(Paths.get(FILE_NAME), 
                hm.entrySet().stream().map(k->k.getKey()+"\r\n"+k.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()), 
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        boolean isFileExist = new File (FILE_NAME).exists();        
        System.out.println("File with name '"+FILE_NAME+"' is exist : " + isFileExist);

        Files.lines(Paths.get(FILE_NAME), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```